# How to run Windows powershell script from python?

Tags: python, windows, powershell

I would like to run a script like in the picture in the Powershell but from python. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7XGI.png For instance, I would like to have a code like this:

```
def run(namefile):
    command that opens powershell
    command that type in the powershell .\spim.exe .\namefile.txt
    command that run the script
```

Does someone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run the exe file you can use [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

If you really want to run it inside the Powershell terminal you can run the Powershell binary with [-Command option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1).